# string comparison in a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have two list having strings

```
l1 = {abc;xyz}  
l2 = {lmn,xyz,abc}
```

I would like to iterate through both list and see if l2 has all elements in l1 or not and also if l1 has all elements in l2 or not.
Order of the strings does not matter. Note that strings has a delimiter ";"
I am using these 2 for loops but the second for loop gives index out of range. Is there a better way to do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < l1.Count; i++)
{
     if (l1[i].Contains(l2[i])) {
          Console.WriteLine("value {0} present in l1", l2[i]);
     }
     else {
          Console.WriteLine("value {0} is not present in l1", l2[i]);
     }
}

for (int i = 0; i < l2.Count; i++)
{
    if (l2[i].Contains(l1[i]))  {
        Console.WriteLine("value {0} present in l2", l2[i]);
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("value {0} is not present in l2", l2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code only works (well, doesn't crash) for lists of the same length. More importantly, they're not actually doing their job - you actually need nested loops - check each string in `l2` for each string in `l1`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `All` method from LINQ:

```
// check whether l2 contains all elements of l1
l1.All(l2.Contains)
// check whether l1 contains all elements of l2
l2.All(l1.Contains)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with linq is better(@Selman22 answer), your issue was in checking count of list that you are trying to get:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < l1.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < l2.Count)
            {
                if (l1[i].Contains(l2[i]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("value {0} present in l1", l2[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("value {0} is not present in l1", l2[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < l2.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < l1.Count)
            {
                if (l2[i].Contains(l1[i]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("value {0} present in l2", l2[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("value {0} is not present in l2", l2[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in additional, you should remove first [] in your loops

```
    for (int i = 0; i < l2.Count; i++)
    {
         if (l1.Contains(l2[i])) {
              Console.WriteLine("value {0} present in l1", l2[i]);
         }
         else {
              Console.WriteLine("value {0} is not present in l1", l2[i]);
         }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < l1.Count; i++)
    {
        if (l2.Contains(l1[i]))  {
            Console.WriteLine("value {0} present in l2", l2[i]);
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("value {0} is not present in l2", l2[i]);
        }
    }
```